# How to refer to a fixed number of things

Tags: counters

Once again I find myself unable to count.
What is the best way to express the following in Japanese

> **The three pigeons** over there are noisy
>
> あそこにいる鳩が3わ煩い (my attempt)
>
> **The four seasons** are spring, summer, autumn and winter
>
> 4の季節は春と夏と秋と冬だ (my different kind of attempt (because I didn't know a counter word for seasons))

(I know there is a special word for all four seasons but that's not the point).

Also does it make a difference whether it is spoken or written. I was told in a previous question that numberのnoun was more of a written thing. Thanks.

Comment: How do we flag an edit?  This one is horrendous!

Comment: @l'électeur rollback ならできますが。

Comment: @l'électeur Click on "edited [time period] ago" to access the revision history, where you can roll back to any previous version. If you rather have a moderator handle it, click on "flag" > "in need of moderator intervention" and explain. (Edits by <1000 users enter the review queue, where they can be rejected. Edits by [>1000](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) users go through automatically and will not be reviewed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do:

> **The three pigeons** over there are noisy
>
> あそこにいる３羽の鳩がうるさい
>
> **The four seasons** are spring, summer, autumn and winter
>
> 季節には、春、夏、秋、冬の４つがある

.

> I was told in a previous question that numberのnoun was more of a written thing

I don't think there is such an expression. You do say `一の重、一の段` etc. but this is not for counting.

Comment: Thanks, I understand your pigeons example, but the four seasons example is confusing me. I didn't think you could put particles after counters e.g. ４つが.

Comment: @user3856370 it's generally used when things are listed up (see https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22%E3%81%AE%E5%9B%9B%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8C%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E2%80%9D). You can also say `四つの季節とは、春、夏、秋、冬である`。`四つの季節は春、夏、秋、冬だ` is grammatically correct but sounds a bit non-native.

Comment: @user3856370 If you're talking about the idea "the four seasons", use 四季 as that's the exact word for it in Japanese. 4つの季節 would sound as if you're explaining to those live where they have seasons other than four.

Comment: 「あそこにいるハト３羽がうるさい」は、どうですか？

Comment: @choco Why is it not あそこにいるハト**が**３羽うるさい rather than あそこにいるハト３羽**が**うるさい

Comment: _Number_ + _adjective_ means "_adjective_-er by _number_".